# How to double encode URI in mailto link?

Tags: javascript, android, mailto

I want to send an e-mail from my phonegap + sencha touch app using a simple mailto-link. The mail contains a body with a link that has a complex JSON string as parameter, which I would like to encode as well, so that the recipient can just click the link. If I just take the JSOn string put in the body and encode the body, the mail body is shown correctly before sending, but if I try to encode the JSON string before adding it to the mailto-link, only subject and mail address and not the body are shown.

This is the source for creating the mailto-link:

```
var key = encodeURIComponent(albumlist);
var msg = {
    subject : "Mein Photoalbum",
    body : "Du wurdest eingeladen Dir mein Photoalbum anzuschauen.\n\n"+
        "Klicke dazu einfach auf folgenden Link:\n"+
        "http://photoalbum.incom-grosche.com/photoalbum/index.html?userid="+
        userid+"&albumlist="+key+" \n\n"+
};
window.location = "mailto:?" + Ext.urlEncode(msg);
```

If I just put albumlist directly instead of key the body is interpreted correctly.

Here's the complete mailto-string before put in window.location:

```
mailto:?subject=Mein%20Photoalbum&body=Du%20wurdest%20eingeladen%20Dir%20mein%20Photoalbum%20anzuschauen.%0A%0AKlicke%20dazu%20einfach%20auf%20folgenden%20Link%3A%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fphotoalbum.incom-grosche.com%2Fphotoalbum%2Findex.html%3Fuserid%3D100798134114820183945%26albumlist%3D%255B%257B'albumid'%253A'5702343608088818753'%252C'authkey'%253A'Gv1sRgCPqpv8yA7OvChQE'%257D%255D%20%0A%0ASollte%20der%20Link%20nicht%20funktionieren%2C%20melde%20Dich%20auf%20http%3A%2F%2Fphotoalbum.incom-grosche.com%2F%20mit%20folgenden%20Angaben%20an%3A%0A%0ABenutzerkennung%3A%20100798134114820183945%0ASchl%C3%BCssel%3A%20%5B%7B'albumid'%3A'5702343608088818753'%2C'authkey'%3A'Gv1sRgCPqpv8yA7OvChQE'%7D%5D
```

Works in Chrome. I'm using Phonegap 1.2 + Sencha Touch 2.0 PR3 + Android 3.1